# Macbook's internal hard drive shutting down every 10-15 seconds

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, sleep

I upgraded my Macbook's internal hard drive from a 400GB Western Digital Scorpio Blue to a 750GB Scorpio Blue and restored from Time Machine.  Despite my energy saver settings, the new drive shuts down after only 15 seconds of inactivity!  Then, when I try to do anything, I get greeted with the beach ball while the drive spins up.  If I play a song (with the sound off), the HD never spins down; I have been doing this to prevent beach balls.  The drive spins down within 10 seconds of stopping the song.

Here are the results of pmset:

```
~$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 womp       0
 lidwake    1
 halfdim    1
 sms        1
 hibernatefile  /var/vm/sleepimage
 disksleep  0
 sleep      45
 hibernatemode  3
 ttyskeepawake  1
 displaysleep   10
 acwake     0
 autorestart    0
```

And, SpindownHD shows that the drive is always active, even though I can hear it shut down.  Is this a bad disk?  Is there something else I can try?  Sorta related, is there a way to monitor hard drive RPM?

Thanks,
Lou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using [hdapm](http://mckinlay.net.nz/hdapm/) to make the drive less aggressive about spinning down.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, there are separate profiles for battery and adaptor power. Check if both profiles are set to never stop harddrive from spinning.

Comment: Yup, both profiles are.